# API-gateway is giving "Resource not found " ERROR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gateway

i am doing pet project, with Eureka server - > Eureka Client(simple microservice with one route) and API gateway

[image: Here is Application properties of Eureka Client]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testMethod(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
 //this is a simple route in my Eureka client
```

this is application.properties of API-Gateway

```
server.port=8082

spring.application.name=api-gateway

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8081/eureka

# Spring Cloud Gateway Configuration
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=eureka-client
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://eureka-client
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/test/main/**

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Eureka server is registered
Eureka-client and Api-Gateway

```
http://localhost:8082/main/test
```

-> when i am calling this route through API-Gateway it is giving me 404
here is the log [image]

Answer (score 1):

The route predicate property in the application.properties file does not match the request URL.

It should be : spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/main/test/**

Comment: same issue, No resource found